# Kinect: unproject depth data from 2D to 3D

Tags: parameters, camera, kinect

I review other discussion but is not clear for me, I apologize for my ignorance and thank you in advance.

I am working with kinect with the depth stream and the skeleton joints. I want to unproject the depth image provided by Kinect from 2D to 3D in order to construct a surface in the space.

The procedure would be easy, I get the intrinsic parameters of my Kinect (from Daniel Herrera Toolkit) and formulate a conversion formula:

```
% Set 1000 to convert the raw depth value to meters.

zw = z_w  / 1000;

xw = (xv - cx) * zw / fx;

yw = (yv - cy) * zw / fy;
```

with depth camera focal length, taked from  the Kinect Toolbox by Daniel Herrera

```
fx = 579.83; % in axis x

fy = 586.73; % in axix y

cx = 321.55;  % optical center x

cy = 235.01;  % optical center y

zw = depth by kinect (mm)
```

and `xv` and `yv` correspond to 2D image coordinate, and `xw`, `yw`, `zw` correspond to the object coordinate in meters, with the origin on the sensor location (0,0,0).

But all the results are not good.

I evaluate a single point to compare my result with the Head 3D coordinate provided by Kinect in my application:

According the 3D skeleton tracker
`Head = [-0.0047,  0.3932,    1.4592]` (3D coordinate in meters)

According my function :

```
xv =  313

yv =  115

zw = 1360

unproject(xv, yv, zw)
```

`POS3D =  [-0.4809    0.1794    1.3500]` (3D coordinate in meters)

As you can observe this two results are different, mainly on the x component.

1. My question is if the formulation is wrong, or any parameters that I use is over-sized.
   If it is a case, can you share with me the function ?
2. Another question, does the skeleton 3D data require post processing to use?.

Thanks,

Comment: Well since the z-coordinate differs as well, it is not (only) because of you formula. You did not tell anything about any framework (NITE? Kinect SDK? ...) so it is hard to guess what's going on.

Comment: Hi Simson, i am sorry, i forgot to say i work with MS Kinet SDK, and

Comment: the color and depth images are registered previously. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Although the formula seems to be correct, something went wrong since if I use it with the provides values, I get a complete different result. But even if it were correct, it might no be the same like the position you get from MS SDK skeleton tracking since [it uses filtering per default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj131024.aspx).
2. It depends on the use case. You e.g. might get a strong jittering if you do not filter the results (see above). But for some cases (e.g. finding a ROI) no postprocessing is needed.